# How I can to process the xml file parsing with Jaxb not from the root element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

Can somebody to give an advice to me with the next situation:
I have such structure in my xml file:

```
    <?xml ... ?>
    <root>
     <listof_aaa>
      <aaa>aaa_object</aaa>
      <aaa>aaa_object</aaa>
      ...
     </listof_aaa>
     <listof_bbb>
      <bbb>bbb_object</bbb>
      <bbb>bbb_object</bbb>
      ...
     </listof_bbb>
     <listof_ccc>
      <ccc>ccc_object</ccc>
      <ccc>ccc_object</ccc>
      ...
     </listof_ccc>
   </root>
```

My goal is to read first all aaa-objects, then bbb and so on...
How can I parse such structure, if in the root tag I have a few different families of objects? I thought about using of JAXB, but can not to understand, how good can I to work with it in this situation.

P.S. All families of objects are POJO.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a XML schema? if yes, what yours autogenerated root class looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typical autogenerated classes in your case would look like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "listof_aaa",
    "listof_bbb",
    "listof_ccc",
    "listinside"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Listof_aaa listof_aaa;
    protected Listof_bbb listof_bbb;
    protected Listof_ccc listof_ccc;
    protected java.util.List<Listinside> listinside // example of multiple elements with one node name under the root

    public Listof_aaa getListof_aaa() {
      return listof_aaa;
    }

    public void setListof_aaa(Listof_aaa value) {
      this.listof_aaa = value;
    }

    // other getters and setters
    // and an example of multiple elements under the root

    public java.util.List<Listinside> getListinside() {
    if (listinside == null) {
        listinside = new ArrayList<Listinside>();
    }
    return this.sec;
}
}
```

iterating:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarhsaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) unmarhsaller.unmarshal(new File("pathToYourFile.xml"));
       Listof_aaa listof_aa = root.getListof_aaa();

       /* and in case of a list */
       List<Listinside> listinside = root.getListinside();
       for (List myList : listinside) {
           // do your stuff
       }
}
```